Python itertools product aborting
When running the code below, python aborts and closes the python prompt:
>>> import itertools
>>> nComb = 2
>>> t = range(nComb)
>>> combs = list(itertools.product(t, repeat=31))

Is there a limit of combinations ?
I only could run until repeat = 25.
As result I would like to have all possible combinations. For Example:
(0, 0, 0, ..., 0)
(0, 0, 0, ..., 1)
etc


The python process was killed automatically because it ran out of RAM, as suggested by Frank Yellin.
Note that for the next value of repeat (repeat = 25 + 1 = 26), MEM is approximately 34G, as measured by top on a MacBookPro, when running your code on Python 3.9.18. If the memory on your computer is smaller than that, your python process will run out of memory. And this is not even counting other processes or applications you may have running at the same time, which consume memory as well.

Your problem is that you're running out of memory.
You could instead try
import np
np.arange(2 ** 31, dtype=np.int32)

You'll get an array of 2**32 elements.  Each element can be treated as a bitmap which you can convert into a tuple as needed.

Tks for the reply but as result I would like to have all possible combinations not an array counting from 1 up to n

But you do have every possible combination.  That's what binary means.  So, for evample, the element[5] is binary 0000....101, which you can turn into a tuple by means of tuple((x >> i) & 1 for i in range(31)).  Each element of the array is a different combination of 0s and 1s.  Iterating through the numpy array, you'll get all 2^31 possible combinations of 0s and 1s.
